# Use of enough with Noun

Tags: adjectives

> Carrying to term a pregnancy against one's will is punishment enough -- in fact, it can amount to torture, according to the United Nations Human Right Council.

I found the above sentence in New York Times.

My question is why enough comes after the noun "punishment" whereas so far I know enough comes before noun like "enough strength"?

Comment: You will find useful explanations of the use of adjectives after nouns at a number of sites including:      
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postpositive_adjective   .........................................                                       https://www.englishgrammar.org/attributive-adjectives-nouns/   ...........................                               and      http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv133.shtml

Answer (score 1):

Postpositive adjectives (that come after the noun) are probably left over from the influence of French on the English language.  In French the adjective normally comes after the noun.

There are three main situations where postpositive adjectives are common:

1. With certain proper nouns, such as titles like *Secretary General*, *Poet Laureate*, and *Heir Apparent*, job descriptions like *Notary Public, Sergeant Major*, and *Prince Consort*, or names of organizations like *Alcoholics Anonymous*, *Jet Blue* and *Verizon Wireless*
2. With common nouns and phrases like *court martial*, *code red*, *whiskey sour*, *battle royale*, and, as in your case, phrases with *enough* like *time enough, food enough*, etc.
3. With words or phrases that the writer wants to make sound *archaic* or *poetic*, as with many book or film titles like *Paradise Lost*, *Hannibal Rising*, and *The Matrix Reloaded*, or dramatic phrases, *They journeyed into lands unseen*, and *In the evening sky appeared the star foretold*.

There are other uses. Postpositive adjectives appear in many phrases *borrowed* from other languages, such as the names of of food (*chicken parmesan*,  *spaghetti bolognese*, etc.), events (*bar mitzvah*), or situations (*carte blanche*) where the words are the same as in the original language.  Also, many Latin legal terms (*mens rea, force majeure, persona non grata*, etc.) are common, especially on certain TV shows.

This is not a complete list.  For more information see:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postpositive_adjective
https://www.englishgrammar.org/attributive-adjectives-nouns/